# How to make python recognize start ,end middle of string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-comparison

I need to compare 2 sequence (or just 2 files) with

seq1 .TT..GCCT..

seq2 TAT.CGCCAC.

```
     2 45   9
```

2, 4, 5, 9  are the positions there are differences and i need to count the distance between them.
I have the script to compare the 2 sequences and count distance but

question 1) I want to ignore the dots(.) at the start and end of sequence but take in account the middle ones. How you do it in python? how is that task called?

question 2) if i have differences one next to the other i need to take that as a block so 2-4 distance will be 2, 2-5 will be ignored, 4-9ignored, 5-9 counted and 2-9 will be 7(will count 4and5 as two), how can i do that?

Comment: Can you `sequence.strip('.')` to remove the leading and trailing `.`?

Comment: no all the character position is important at the final output. if i remove starting and ending dots i will change them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i figure out a way and i wonder if there is something more simple.
i will retype the questions first

if you have a list 
`a = [1, 2, 3, 7, 10, 11, 12, 18, 20, 21]`

question 1) how you will remove **only** the leading and trailing groups of consecutive values (leading is defined by having number 1 inside and trailing by having 21) and end with a list `b = [7, 10, 11, 12, 18]`.

question
 2) how you will count the distance between those numbers and end with a list c = [3, 4] ( it treats the consecutive numbers as a block and does 10-7=3, then 18-12=4).
My solytion:

`consec = []
    for key, group in groupby(enumerate(a), lambda i: i[0] - i[1]):
        consec.append(list(map(itemgetter(1), group)))
    consecHead = consec[0]
    consecTail = consec[-1]
    if 1 in consecHead:
        consecHeadcheck = consecHead
    else:
        consecHeadcheck = []
    if 21 in consecTail:
        consecTailcheck = consecTail
    else:
        consecTailcheck = []
    b_prior = [x for x in polPos if x not in consecTailcheck]
    b = [x for x in b_prior if x not in consecHeadcheck]
    print(b)
    c = []
    for i in range(len(b)): 
                   if int(int(b[i+1]) - int(b[i])) !=1:
                         c.append(int(b[i+1]) - int(b[i])
    print(c)`

Answer (score -1):

Question 1) strip_seq1 = seq1[1:len(seq)-1] and the same for seq2 to remove the (.) at the start and end while preserving everything in between.

Question 2) I'm not sure what your asking, sorry.